# Mac OS X Lion Safari Doesn't Display Tab Bar in Full Screen Mode

Tags: safari

In the recent developer preview(2) of Mac OS X Lion, Safari no longer displays Tab Bar when put into the Full Screen mode. You have to move the pointer to the top to see the Tab Bar, which is very annoying for people who mostly work with keyboard.

Is there any quick fix? Or should we just take a nap and see how the final version will look like?

Comment: This is a question about prerelease software, which changes quickly and often. Any problem and answers will probably vanish or change by the release.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with keybord mainly try Cmd + Shift + Arrow Keys or [ and ]. You should be able to cycle your tabs like that. I dont have the Developer Preview, so I dont know if there is any quick fix, and I dont think Apple will change it in its final version. After all this is how all major browsers work in fullscreen mode: they all hide the tab bar so you focus on the content... :/

Anyway, Hope it helps!
Kevin

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. That's right;however, that way you just go through the tabs, but can never see the title of the tab.